# Mysql query staying in 'SENDING DATA' state for long time when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have query which is going in the **SENDING DATA** state for very long period of time.
Can someone please help me with this : below are details

**Mysql Query:**

```
select a.msgId,a.senderId,a.destination,a.inTime,a.status as InStatus,b.status as SubStatus,c.deliverTime,substr(c.receipt,82,7) as DlvStatus 
from inserted_history a  left join submitted_history b  on b.msgId = a.msgId left join delivered_history c  on a.msgId = c.msgId 
where a.inTime between '2010-08-10 00:00:00' and '2010-08-010 23:59:59' and a.systemId='ND_arber'
```

Total records in `delivered_history` : **223870168**

Total records in `inserted_history` : **264817239**

Total records in `submitted_history` : **226637058**

**Explain** query returns:

```
id  ,  select_type  ,  table  ,  type  ,  possible_keys  ,  key  ,  key_len  ,  ref  ,  rows  ,  Extra  
  1  ,  SIMPLE  ,  a  ,  ref  ,  systemId,idx_time  ,  systemId  ,  14  ,  const  ,  735310  ,  Using where  
  1  ,  SIMPLE  ,  b  ,  ref  ,  PRIMARY  ,  PRIMARY  ,  66  ,  gwreports2.a.msgId  ,  2270405  ,    
  1  ,  SIMPLE  ,  c  ,  ref  ,  PRIMARY  ,  PRIMARY  ,  66  ,  gwreports2.a.msgId  ,  2238701  ,
```

**CREATE TABLE for delivered_history**

```
CREATE TABLE `delivered_history` (
 `msgId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `systemId` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 `deliverTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `smscId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `smsc` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 `receipt` BLOB NULL,
 `errcode` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`msgId`, `deliverTime`),
 INDEX `systemId` (`systemId`),
 INDEX `smsc` (`smsc`),
 INDEX `idx_time` (`deliverTime`)
)
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

**CREATE TABLE for inserted_history**

```
CREATE TABLE `inserted_history` (
 `msgId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `systemId` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 `senderId` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `destination` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `inTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `status` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 `msgText` BLOB NULL,
 `msgType` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`msgId`, `inTime`),
 INDEX `systemId` (`systemId`),
 INDEX `senderId` (`senderId`),
 INDEX `destination` (`destination`),
 INDEX `status` (`status`),
 INDEX `idx_time` (`inTime`)
)
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

**CREATE TABLE for submitted_history**

```
CREATE TABLE `submitted_history` (
 `msgId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `systemId` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 `submitTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `status` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 `smscId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `smsc` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 `errcode` INT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`msgId`, `submitTime`),
 INDEX `systemId` (`systemId`),
 INDEX `smsc` (`smsc`),
 INDEX `status` (`status`),
 INDEX `idx_time` (`submitTime`)
)
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

**ALL TABLES ARE DATE PARTIONED** on the timestamp fields

List of the global variables in `Mysql Server`

```
Variable_name  ,  Value  
  auto_increment_increment  ,  1  
  auto_increment_offset  ,  1  
  autocommit  ,  ON  
  automatic_sp_privileges  ,  ON  
  back_log  ,  50  
  basedir  ,  /usr/  
  big_tables  ,  OFF  
  binlog_cache_size  ,  32768  
  binlog_format  ,  STATEMENT  
  bulk_insert_buffer_size  ,  8388608  
  character_set_client  ,  latin1  
  character_set_connection  ,  latin1  
  character_set_database  ,  latin1  
  character_set_filesystem  ,  binary  
  character_set_results  ,  latin1  
  character_set_server  ,  latin1  
  character_set_system  ,  utf8  
  character_sets_dir  ,  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/  
  collation_connection  ,  latin1_swedish_ci  
  collation_database  ,  latin1_swedish_ci  
  collation_server  ,  latin1_swedish_ci  
  completion_type  ,  0  
  concurrent_insert  ,  1  
  connect_timeout  ,  10  
  datadir  ,  /var/lib/mysql/  
  date_format  ,  %Y-%m-%d  
  datetime_format  ,  %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s  
  default_week_format  ,  0  
  delay_key_write  ,  ON  
  delayed_insert_limit  ,  100  
  delayed_insert_timeout  ,  300  
  delayed_queue_size  ,  1000  
  div_precision_increment  ,  4  
  engine_condition_pushdown  ,  ON  
  error_count  ,  0  
  event_scheduler  ,  OFF  
  expire_logs_days  ,  10  
  flush  ,  OFF  
  flush_time  ,  0  
  foreign_key_checks  ,  ON  
  ft_boolean_syntax  ,  + -><()~*:        &|  
  ft_max_word_len  ,  84  
  ft_min_word_len  ,  4  
  ft_query_expansion_limit  ,  20  
  ft_stopword_file  ,  (built-in)  
  general_log  ,  OFF  
  general_log_file  ,  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.log  
  group_concat_max_len  ,  1024  
  have_community_features  ,  YES  
  have_compress  ,  YES  
  have_crypt  ,  YES  
  have_csv  ,  YES  
  have_dynamic_loading  ,  YES  
  have_geometry  ,  YES  
  have_innodb  ,  YES  
  have_ndbcluster  ,  NO  
  have_openssl  ,  DISABLED  
  have_partitioning  ,  YES  
  have_query_cache  ,  YES  
  have_rtree_keys  ,  YES  
  have_ssl  ,  DISABLED  
  have_symlink  ,  YES  
  hostname  ,  smscdb  
  identity  ,  0  
  ignore_builtin_innodb  ,  OFF  
  init_connect  ,    
  init_file  ,    
  init_slave  ,    
  innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ,  ON  
  innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  ,  1048576  
  innodb_autoextend_increment  ,  8  
  innodb_autoinc_lock_mode  ,  1  
  innodb_buffer_pool_size  ,  8388608  
  innodb_checksums  ,  ON  
  innodb_commit_concurrency  ,  0  
  innodb_concurrency_tickets  ,  500  
  innodb_data_file_path  ,  ibdata1:10M:autoextend  
  innodb_data_home_dir  ,    
  innodb_doublewrite  ,  ON  
  innodb_fast_shutdown  ,  1  
  innodb_file_io_threads  ,  4  
  innodb_file_per_table  ,  OFF  
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  ,  1  
  innodb_flush_method  ,    
  innodb_force_recovery  ,  0  
  innodb_lock_wait_timeout  ,  50  
  innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  ,  OFF  
  innodb_log_buffer_size  ,  1048576  
  innodb_log_file_size  ,  5242880  
  innodb_log_files_in_group  ,  2  
  innodb_log_group_home_dir  ,  ./  
  innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  ,  90  
  innodb_max_purge_lag  ,  0  
  innodb_mirrored_log_groups  ,  1  
  innodb_open_files  ,  300  
  innodb_rollback_on_timeout  ,  OFF  
  innodb_stats_on_metadata  ,  ON  
  innodb_support_xa  ,  ON  
  innodb_sync_spin_loops  ,  20  
  innodb_table_locks  ,  ON  
  innodb_thread_concurrency  ,  8  
  innodb_thread_sleep_delay  ,  10000  
  innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm  ,  ON  
  insert_id  ,  0  
  interactive_timeout  ,  28800  
  join_buffer_size  ,  131072  
  keep_files_on_create  ,  OFF  
  key_buffer_size  ,  1073741824  
  key_cache_age_threshold  ,  300  
  key_cache_block_size  ,  1024  
  key_cache_division_limit  ,  100  
  language  ,  /usr/share/mysql/english/  
  large_files_support  ,  ON  
  large_page_size  ,  0  
  large_pages  ,  OFF  
  last_insert_id  ,  0  
  lc_time_names  ,  en_US  
  license  ,  GPL  
  local_infile  ,  ON  
  locked_in_memory  ,  OFF  
  log  ,  OFF  
  log_bin  ,  ON  
  log_bin_trust_function_creators  ,  OFF  
  log_bin_trust_routine_creators  ,  OFF  
  log_error  ,    
  log_output  ,  FILE  
  log_queries_not_using_indexes  ,  OFF  
  log_slave_updates  ,  OFF  
  log_slow_queries  ,  OFF  
  log_warnings  ,  1  
  long_query_time  ,  10.000000  
  low_priority_updates  ,  OFF  
  lower_case_file_system  ,  OFF  
  lower_case_table_names  ,  0  
  max_allowed_packet  ,  536870912  
  max_binlog_cache_size  ,  4294963200  
  max_binlog_size  ,  104857600  
  max_connect_errors  ,  10  
  max_connections  ,  151  
  max_delayed_threads  ,  20  
  max_error_count  ,  64  
  max_heap_table_size  ,  16777216  
  max_insert_delayed_threads  ,  20  
  max_join_size  ,  18446744073709551615  
  max_length_for_sort_data  ,  1024  
  max_prepared_stmt_count  ,  16382  
  max_relay_log_size  ,  0  
  max_seeks_for_key  ,  4294967295  
  max_sort_length  ,  1024  
  max_sp_recursion_depth  ,  0  
  max_tmp_tables  ,  32  
  max_user_connections  ,  0  
  max_write_lock_count  ,  4294967295  
  min_examined_row_limit  ,  0  
  multi_range_count  ,  256  
  myisam_data_pointer_size  ,  6  
  myisam_max_sort_file_size  ,  2146435072  
  myisam_recover_options  ,  BACKUP  
  myisam_repair_threads  ,  1  
  myisam_sort_buffer_size  ,  8388608  
  myisam_stats_method  ,  nulls_unequal  
  myisam_use_mmap  ,  OFF  
  net_buffer_length  ,  16384  
  net_read_timeout  ,  30  
  net_retry_count  ,  10  
  net_write_timeout  ,  60  
  new  ,  OFF  
  old  ,  OFF  
  old_alter_table  ,  OFF  
  old_passwords  ,  OFF  
  open_files_limit  ,  20000  
  optimizer_prune_level  ,  1  
  optimizer_search_depth  ,  62  
  optimizer_switch  ,  index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on  
  pid_file  ,  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid  
  plugin_dir  ,  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin  
  port  ,  3306  
  preload_buffer_size  ,  32768  
  profiling  ,  OFF  
  profiling_history_size  ,  15  
  protocol_version  ,  10  
  pseudo_thread_id  ,  0  
  query_alloc_block_size  ,  8192  
  query_cache_limit  ,  1073741824  
  query_cache_min_res_unit  ,  4096  
  query_cache_size  ,  536870912  
  query_cache_type  ,  ON  
  query_cache_wlock_invalidate  ,  OFF  
  query_prealloc_size  ,  8192  
  rand_seed1  ,    
  rand_seed2  ,    
  range_alloc_block_size  ,  4096  
  read_buffer_size  ,  131072  
  read_only  ,  OFF  
  read_rnd_buffer_size  ,  33554432  
  relay_log  ,    
  relay_log_index  ,    
  relay_log_info_file  ,  relay-log.info  
  relay_log_purge  ,  ON  
  relay_log_space_limit  ,  0  
  report_host  ,    
  report_password  ,    
  report_port  ,  3306  
  report_user  ,    
  rpl_recovery_rank  ,  0  
  secure_auth  ,  OFF  
  secure_file_priv  ,    
  server_id  ,  3  
  skip_external_locking  ,  ON  
  skip_networking  ,  OFF  
  skip_show_database  ,  OFF  
  slave_compressed_protocol  ,  OFF  
  slave_exec_mode  ,  STRICT  
  slave_load_tmpdir  ,  /tmp  
  slave_net_timeout  ,  3600  
  slave_skip_errors  ,  OFF  
  slave_transaction_retries  ,  10  
  slow_launch_time  ,  2  
  slow_query_log  ,  OFF  
  slow_query_log_file  ,  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-slow.log  
  socket  ,  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  
  sort_buffer_size  ,  67108864  
  sql_auto_is_null  ,  ON  
  sql_big_selects  ,  ON  
  sql_big_tables  ,  OFF  
  sql_buffer_result  ,  OFF  
  sql_log_bin  ,  ON  
  sql_log_off  ,  OFF  
  sql_log_update  ,  ON  
  sql_low_priority_updates  ,  OFF  
  sql_max_join_size  ,  18446744073709551615  
  sql_mode  ,    
  sql_notes  ,  ON  
  sql_quote_show_create  ,  ON  
  sql_safe_updates  ,  OFF  
  sql_select_limit  ,  18446744073709551615  
  sql_slave_skip_counter  ,    
  sql_warnings  ,  OFF  
  ssl_ca  ,    
  ssl_capath  ,    
  ssl_cert  ,    
  ssl_cipher  ,    
  ssl_key  ,    
  storage_engine  ,  MyISAM  
  sync_binlog  ,  0  
  sync_frm  ,  ON  
  system_time_zone  ,  IST  
  table_definition_cache  ,  256  
  table_lock_wait_timeout  ,  50  
  table_open_cache  ,  500  
  table_type  ,  MyISAM  
  thread_cache_size  ,  8  
  thread_handling  ,  one-thread-per-connection  
  thread_stack  ,  196608  
  time_format  ,  %H:%i:%s  
  time_zone  ,  SYSTEM  
  timed_mutexes  ,  OFF  
  timestamp  ,  1282125419  
  tmp_table_size  ,  16777216  
  tmpdir  ,  /tmp  
  transaction_alloc_block_size  ,  8192  
  transaction_prealloc_size  ,  4096  
  tx_isolation  ,  REPEATABLE-READ  
  unique_checks  ,  ON  
  updatable_views_with_limit  ,  YES  
  version  ,  5.1.37-1ubuntu5-log  
  version_comment  ,  (Ubuntu)  
  version_compile_machine  ,  i486  
  version_compile_os  ,  debian-linux-gnu  
  wait_timeout  ,  28800  
  warning_count  ,  0
```

Answer (score 12):

Your explain plan that you gave:

```
id , select_type , table , type , possible_keys      , key      , key_len  , ref                 , rows , Extra
1  , SIMPLE      , a     , ref  , systemId idx_time) , systemId , 14       , const              , 735310 , Using where
1  , SIMPLE      , b     , ref  , PRIMARY            , PRIMARY  , 66       , gwreports2.a.msgId , 2270405 ,
1  , SIMPLE      , c     , ref  , PRIMARY            , PRIMARY  , 66       , gwreports2.a.msgId , 2238701 ,
```

shows that you are hitting: 735310 * 2270405 * 2238701 = **3T rows!!!!!!**
Effectively your not using your indexes to their fullest potential.

How to interpret your 'explain plan': 
     For every row in table 'a' (735310 ), you hit table 'b' 2270405  times.
     For every row you hit in table 'b', you hit table 'c' 2238701  times.
     As you can see, this is an exponential problem.

Yes, the 8MB of InnoDb Buffer space is small, but getting your explain plan down to xxxx * 1 * 1 will result in incredible speeds, even for 8MB of Buffer Space.

Given your Query:

```
SELECT a.msgId,a.senderId,a.destination,a.inTime,a.status as InStatus,b.status as SubStatus,c.deliverTime,substr(c.receipt,82,7) as DlvStatus 
  FROM inserted_history a
  LEFT JOIN submitted_history b ON b.msgId = a.msgId  -- USES 1 column of PK
  LEFT JOIN delivered_history c ON a.msgId = c.msgId  -- USES 1 column of PK 
 WHERE a.inTime BETWEEN '2010-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2010-08-010 23:59:59' -- NO key 
   AND a.systemId='ND_arber' -- Uses non-unique PK
```

Here are the problems I see:
   A) Your _history tables are partitioned on the columns with 'Timestamp' datatype, YET you are NOT those columns in your JOIN/WHERE criteria.  The engine must hit EVERY partition without that information.
   B) Access to submitted_history and delivered_history is using only 1 column of a 2-column PK.  You are only getting partial benefit of the PK.  Can you get more columns to be part of the JOIN?  You must get the # of rows found for this table as close to '1' as possible.
   C) msgID = varchar(64)  and this is the 1st column of the PK for each table.  Your Keys on each table are ** *HUGE* **!!
      - Try to reduce the size of columns for the PK, or use different columns.

Your data patterns of the other keys shows that you have LOTS of disk/ram space tied up in non-PK keys.

Question 1) What does "Show Indexes FROM " ([Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-index.html)) for each of the tables report??  The column 'Cardinality' will show you how effective each of your keys really are.  The smaller the cardinality is, the WORST/Less effective that index is.  You want cardinality as close to "total rows" as possible for ideal performance.

Question 2) Can you re-factor the SQL such that the JOIN'd columns of each table are those with the highest cardinality for that table?

Question 3) Is the columns of 'timestamp' datatype really the best column for the partitioning?  If your access patterns always use 'msgId', and msgId is the 1st column of the PK, then .

Question 4) Is msgId unique?  My guess is yes, and the 2nd column of the PK is not really necessary.

Read up on Optimizing SQL ([Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html)) and have the index cardinality reports of your tables. This is the path to figure out how to optimize an query.    You want the 'rows' of the explain plan to be N * 1 * 1.

SIDE NOTE:InnoDb & MyISAM engines does NOT automatically update table cardinality for non-unique columns, the DBA needs to manually run 'Analyze Table' periodically to ensure its accuracy.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to alter the index of inserted_history,

systemId (systemId)

to be

systemId (systemId, inTime). Or add an additional index

My logic being that this should help to speed up the selection of the inserted_history (a) rows which forms the basis of the join.

The where clause "where a.inTime between '2010-08-10 00:00:00' and '2010-08-010 23:59:59' and a.systemId='ND_arber'" would all be selectable by index. At present, rows are selectable by systemId but then all those rows need to be scanned for the time.

Just as a matter of interest, how many records would there be (on average) for each system id. Also as msgid is not unique on its own, how many records (on average) in the other tables will have teh same msgid.

Answer (score 0):

**Main Idea**

Are you using InnoDB? It looks like your buffer pool is only 8MB. That could easily be the problem, you're dealing with a lot of data and InnoDB doesn't have much memory. Can you bump the innodb_buffer_pool_size up? You'll have to restart MySQL, but I'm betting that would make a HUGE difference, even if you only give it 256 or 512MB.

Update: I see your storage engine and table format seem to default to MyISAM, so unless you specified otherwise this wouldn't apply. I wonder if the myisam_sort_buffer_size would help? We don't use MyISAM so I'm not familiar with tuning it.

**Random Thought**

I wonder if having having the primary key be alphanumeric (especially VARCHAR) has anything to do with it. I remember we had problems with performance on non-numeric primary keys, but that database dated from 4.0 or 4.1, so that may not apply (or ever have been true).

**Secondary Idea**

After the memory thing above, my best guess would be to give MySQL more hints. When I have a query that's running slow, I often find giving it more information helps it out. You have messageId/time indexes on each table. Maybe something more like this would work better:

```
select a.msgId,a.senderId,a.destination,a.inTime,a.status as InStatus,
b.status as SubStatus,c.deliverTime,substr(c.receipt,82,7) as DlvStatus
from inserted_history a left join submitted_history b on b.msgId = a.msgId
left join delivered_history c on a.msgId = c.msgId
where a.inTime between '2010-08-10 00:00:00' and '2010-08-010 23:59:59'
and a.systemId='ND_arber' AND c.inTime between b.inTime >= a.inTime
and c.inTime >= b.inTime
```

I'm guessing things get inserted into A, then B, then C. If you have better limits (say when something goes in A, it's always sent out and submitted within one day) add that information could help.

I wonder about this both because I've seen it help my query performance in some situations, but also because you have the data partitioned on the datetime. That may help the optimizer.

My other suggestion would be to run your query for a short amount of time, say 10 minutes instead of a full day, and make sure the results are right. Then try 30. Increase it and see when it falls off into "come back tomorrow" territory. That may tell you something.